# React: why state is updated only at handleChage of input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this Component:

```js
export const DashboardPage = () => {

    const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);
    const [currentNumber, setCurrentNumber] = useState(null);
    const [insertedNumber, setInsertedNumber] = useState(null);
    const [result, setResult] = useState(null);
    const [arrayNumbers, setArrayNumbers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const rnd = randomNumber();
        if (!mounted) {
            setCurrentNumber(rnd);
            setMounted(true);
        }
    }, [mounted]);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setInsertedNumber(e.target.value);
        
    }

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        arrayNumbers.push(insertedNumber);
        setArrayNumbers(arrayNumbers);
        setResult("Oops, ritenta! era " + currentNumber)
        if (parseInt(insertedNumber) === parseInt(currentNumber)) {
            setResult("EVVIVA hai vinto!");
        }
    }

    const handleOnSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    
    return (
        <>
            <h2>Storico tentativi: {arrayNumbers.map(e => e)}</h2>
            <h2>La soluzione è: {currentNumber}</h2>
            <Form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
                <Form.Group controlId="formGTN">
                    <Form.Label>Guess the number:</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
                </Form.Group>
                <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={handleClick} label="Is it?" />
            </Form>
            <h1>{result}</h1>
        </>
    )
}


export default DashboardPage;
```

It is a simple "Guess The Number" play.

I have the issue that:

1. On very first loading of page, I can get into `arrayNumbers` the only one number I inserted.
2. From second and other attempts, when I `CHANGE` the value inside the input, so when I delete previous number, I get state update and I have the previous (and on) numbers. Like if "state" is "back" of one try.

I can see this behavious also in Chrome's Redux plugin. State is update ONLY a step other.

I could move the push into array on onChange, but... If I insert a number of 2 digits I get 2 insert on array (44 will be "4" and "4").

THank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never mutate the state and/or update the state without `setState`. In JavaScript, the [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method mutates the original array. So, in your example, you mutate `arrayNumbers` but you should add a new element to the array without updating the original one.

Also, listening to the `onSubmit` event is enough, you don't have to add the `onClick` event to your submit button. You can move everything from `handleClick` to `handleOnSubmit`.

```js
export const DashboardPage = () => {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);
  const [currentNumber, setCurrentNumber] = useState(null);
  const [insertedNumber, setInsertedNumber] = useState(null);
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);
  const [arrayNumbers, setArrayNumbers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const rnd = randomNumber();
    if (!mounted) {
      setCurrentNumber(rnd);
      setMounted(true);
    }
  }, [mounted]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInsertedNumber(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleOnSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setArrayNumbers([...arrayNumbers, insertedNumber]);

    if (parseInt(insertedNumber, 10) === parseInt(currentNumber, 10)) {
      setResult('EVVIVA hai vinto!');
    } else {
      setResult('Oops, ritenta! era ' + currentNumber);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Storico tentativi: {arrayNumbers.map((e) => e)}</h2>
      <h2>La soluzione è: {currentNumber}</h2>
      <Form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
        <Form.Group controlId="formGTN">
          <Form.Label>Guess the number:</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
        </Form.Group>
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit" label="Is it?" />
      </Form>
      <h1>{result}</h1>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For the above component, you might try these changes in the handleClick function:

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let newArr = [...arrayNumbers];
  newArr.push(insertedNumber);
  setArrayNumbers(newArr);
  setResult('Oops, ritenta! era ' + currentNumber);
  if (parseInt(insertedNumber) === parseInt(currentNumber)) {
    setResult('EVVIVA hai vinto!');
  }
};
```